# Building golang application results in 'TARGET_OS_IPHONE' is not defined error

Tags: macos, go, build, cgo

I was trying to build my go app as usual.
But after a recent mac update, I got the following error:

```
# runtime/cgo
In file included from gcc_context.c:8:
In file included from /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo/libcgo.h:7:
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:220:5: error: 'TARGET_OS_IPHONE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
```

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to add the following parameters to the `CGO_CPPFLAGS` environment variable.

```
CGO_CPPFLAGS=-DTARGET_OS_IPHONE
```